# What is the meaning of the values of the Protocols field from Get-TlsCipherSuite Output?

Tags: windows, ssl, powershell

Powershell has a [`Get-TlsCipherSute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/tls/get-tlsciphersuite?view=win10-ps) cmdlet that returns information about which ciphers TLS can use.

The output includes a `Protocols` field that seems to be set to an array of numbers, for Example:

```
PS C:\>Get-TlsCipherSuite -Name "AES"
KeyType               : 0
Certificate           : ECDSA
MaximumExchangeLength : 65536
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              : ECDH
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  :
CipherBlockLength     : 16
CipherLength          : 256
BaseCipherSuite       : 49196
CipherSuite           : 49196
Cipher                : AES
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Protocols             : {771, 65277}
```

What is the meaning of the numbers that are the value of the `Protocols` field for each cipher suite (for example, `771` and `652677`)?

*Note*: If you go exploring, note that the output of this command doesn't seem to behave with `select`, see https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/16511008-get-tlsciphersuite-does-not-output-well-behaved-ob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They seem to be a decimal representation of the value used in the [TLS Version Field](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29314/4018). **771 = 0x0303 = TLS_1_2**, and **65277 = 0xFEFD = DTLS_1_1**. You can see similar constants defined in [various TLS libraries](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/blob/eb6df1c940527e65e3f16c662836d7382ba4ace0/scapy_ssl_tls/ssl_tls.py#L241):

```
TLS_VERSIONS = {
    # SSL
    0x0002: "SSL_2_0", # 2
    0x0300: "SSL_3_0", # 768
    # TLS:
    0x0301: "TLS_1_0", # 769
    0x0302: "TLS_1_1", # 770
    0x0303: "TLS_1_2", # 771
    0x0304: "TLS_1_3", # 772
    # DTLS
    0x0100: "PROTOCOL_DTLS_1_0_OPENSSL_PRE_0_9_8f", # 256
    0x7f10: "TLS_1_3_DRAFT_16", # 32528
    0x7f12: "TLS_1_3_DRAFT_18", # 32530
    0xfeff: "DTLS_1_0", # 65279
    0xfefd: "DTLS_1_1", # 65277
}
```

So they likely represent the TLS/SSL protocol versions for which that cipher is available.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the decimal equivalent for each hex number to make this an easier reference since Powershell's Get-TlsCipherSute returns them in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
TLS_VERSIONS = {
    # SSL
    2       0x0002: "SSL_2_0",
    768     0x0300: "SSL_3_0",
    # TLS:
    769     0x0301: "TLS_1_0",
    770     0x0302: "TLS_1_1",
    771     0x0303: "TLS_1_2",
    772     0x0304: "TLS_1_3",
    # DTLS
    256     0x0100: "PROTOCOL_DTLS_1_0_OPENSSL_PRE_0_9_8f",
    32528   0x7f10: "TLS_1_3_DRAFT_16",
    32530   0x7f12: "TLS_1_3_DRAFT_18",
    65279   0xfeff: "DTLS_1_0",
    65277   0xfefd: "DTLS_1_1",
}
```